# Coherent and non-coherent caches

Tags: caching, x86, cpu-architecture, gpu

I would like to clarify a few questions regarding architectures containing coherent and non-coherent caches. As a specific example I'll be referring to the [article](https://techdecoded.intel.io/resources/dpc-for-intel-processor-graphics-architecture/?cid=em&source=elo&campid=iags_WW_iagsdn_EMNL_EN_2020_CPDP%20Sept%202020%20Newsletter_C-MKA-16355_T-MKA-20339&content=iags_WW_iagsdn_EMNL_EN_2020_CPDP%20Sept%202020%20Newsletter_C-MKA-16355_T-MKA-20339&elq_cid=6133442&em_id=61180&elqrid=918f0e5dc9ea4075816500fbdebc36eb&elqcampid=40225&erpm_id=9232612#gs.gjk1ff) describing Intel Computer Graphics Archirecture.

In short, let's say we have a processor with integrated graphics on the same die. The integrated GPU shares the last-level cache (LLC) with the CPU. The GPU contains many execution units (EUs) combined into subslices each having private L1 and L2 caches (**non-coherent** with CPU). These subslices are aggregated to form a slice, which consists of a shared L3 cache (**coherent** with the CPU) and a banked shared local memory (SLM).

[image]

As long as there non-coherent caches in this architecture, how can it guarantee that a stale value would not be read by EU or a CPU core?

I suspect it may require memory barriers to enforce coherence. Or what kind of a difference does coherent and non-coherent cache hardware make for a programmer?

In case a programmer is the one who is responsible for maintaining coherence, what is the purpose of making some cache levels coherent with CPU (in this example, L3 cache of GPU slices)? As the programmer can't be sure whether data belongs to a coherent or non-coherent cache, doesn't it mean that he would have to insert memory barriers *anyway*?

Comment: Note that the non-coherent caches are only inside the GPU, so communication between CPUs, and making the CPU put data where the GPU can see it, doesn't require any explicit flushing by the CPU cores.  I don't know much about Intel GPUs; presumably the drivers can tell them when to invalidate / sync their caches with coherent L3.

Comment: Also, CPU memory barrier instructions don't create coherency, only order between local operations.  CPUs already drain their store buffer to coherent L1d cache as fast as they can; a barrier just makes execution of later loads wait for that to happen on its own.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for your information. I just want to clarify your words saying that communication between CPUs and GPU doesn't require any explicit flushing by the CPU cores. When multiple cores read and write the same block of data we need protocols like MSI to ensure that all cores see the same data. Similarly, what if CPU and GPU operate on the same block of data? Is it possible?

Comment: I only said the *CPU* side is simple.  For CPU<-> GPU like you're asking about, the GPU side *does* have to worry about flushing its stores to where the CPU can see it, and making sure its reads check L3 cache instead of reading potentially stale non-coherent caches, for data the CPU may have changed.  I assume some kind of message passing is necessary for the GPU to know when to clear or sync its non-coherent caches, vs. when it can let those caches do their job.

Comment: The main communication channel between the CPU and the GPU is the system memory (a.k.a. the RAM, or Main memory in Intel's docs). The L3 shortcut is an optimization that speeds up the communication but the CPU and the GPU are separate devices with their own internal memories (where present) and the communication happens like with any other device: MMIO and DMA (and sometimes with Port mapped IO). When an EU needs to write something to the RAM it will probably use the right page attributes, since GPUs also have an MMU, so that the stores go to the "main memory" (in truth they stop in the L3).

Comment: @MargaretBloom To my knowledge, most caches today use a write-back policy, so the data is stored to the main memory only when the corresponding block is evicted from the cache. Thus, the memory may not have an up-to-date value and cache coherence needs to be maintained. In CPUs protocols like MSI, MESI, MOESI etc take care of that. But here the GPU has some non-coherent caches, so I was wondering how that would work if a GPU subslice and a CPU core happened to have the same data block in their caches. Also why do we care about GPU L3 being coherent with the CPU, but not L1 or L2?

Comment: @mentalmushroom The cache policy depends on the specific use of the memory. The GPU needs data from the CPU and needs (much less often) to publish data for the CPU but these are the *initial* and *final* data sets, for example, they may be a set of vertex buffers on input and a texture surface on output. Any intermediary result is written to the non-coherent (read private) caches of the GPU and there is no direct access to them. The GPU shares the L3 because the L3 is off-CPU-cores (while the L1 and L2 are not (just exactly it is for the GPU L1 and L2 which are "in-GPU-core").